# Javascript regex get the number only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
Thank You - Your Order Number Is 5396450
```

I want a regex to to get the number only. Using `[0-9]` only gets me `5`, and `[0-9]*` returns nothing.

The string will always be the same it is the number that changes.

How can I get everything after `"Is "`?

Comment: just change `*` to `+`

Comment: I'm confused why `[0-9]*` returns nothing if `[0-9]` returns 5. If it's greedy matching, then this should give you the full string of numbers. What is your javascript code for this?

Comment: As @Chris has pointed out, it's unclear what the problem is without you showing your code. Please edit your question to show exactly what you are trying to do and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get everything after "Is "?

```
IS\s*(\S+)
```

Group Index 1 contains the string you want. Change `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+` inorder to match one or more numbers.

```
> "Thank You - Your Order Number Is 5396450".match(/Is\s*(\S+)/)[1];
'5396450'
> "Thank You - Your Order Number Is 5396450".match(/\d+/)[0];
'5396450'
> "Thank You - Your Order Number Is 5396450".match(/\S+$/)[0];
'5396450'
```

Comment: the string will always be same.There's really no need for IS et

Answer (score 0):

If the number is always at the end of the string, you could use this regular expression: `/\d+$/`. This matches one or more digits at the end of the string.

Testing it out:

```
> "Thank You - Your Order Number Is 5396450".match(/\d+$/)[0]
"5396450"
```